# Test with Jest in Vue failing in child component because of lodash

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

In my Vue app, lodash is loaded globally as a Vue plugin in `main.js`:

```html
import _ from "lodash"

export default function install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype._ = _
    Vue.mixin({
        computed: {
            _: () => _
        }
    })
}
```

Then, I have a child component using a lodash function and I'm trying to `shallowMount` its parent, but when I run the test it is failing with this error:

```html
ReferenceError: _ is not defined

      270 |         },
    > 272 |         debouncedSearch: _.debounce(
          | ^
      273 |             function (value) {
      274 |                 this.currentQuery = value
      275 |                 if (!_.isEmpty(this.currentQuery)) {
```

What I'm missing here?

**Solution:**

After looking into the awnser marked as correct I've added `import debounce from "lodash/debounce"` and replaced `_.debounce()` with `debounce` and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-writing your function like this:

```
// Lodash is not defined out here
debouncedSearch: function() {
    // But is available in here
    return _.debounce(
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Writing the method like that won't trigger the function inside _.debounce() with a click event. Don't know why, that's the only way I've found that worked. But you're correct, that's the reason why Jest is failing the tests.